# case_when or ifelse for building a new varaible

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to build a new variable base on some condition. My codes look like:

```
df%>% mutate (PassFL= case_when(ID %in% PassID$ID~"Y",
                                ID !%in% PassID$ID~"N")
```

It won't run. I think `!%in%` is incorrect. How should I correct it.

Also, I have some difficulty follow `ifelse`. Often forget `)` or lost track. Could anyone give some tips on how to follow `ifelse`? Is any disadvatage of using `case_when`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!%in%` would not work, it would be `!ID %in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% 
     mutate (PassFL= case_when(ID %in% PassID$ID~"Y",
                            !ID %in% PassID$ID~"N"))
```

---

Or if there are only two values to be considered, can create the expression on one, and specify the default as the next (`TRUE ~`)

```
df %>%
   mutate(PassFL = case_when(ID %in% PassID$ID ~ "Y", TRUE ~ "N"))
```

---

Or without using `ifelse` or `case_when`, can convert the logical to numeric index (TRUE -> 1 and FALSE ->0, so we add 1 as `R` indexing starts from 1) and use that to substitute values passed in a `vector`

```
df %>%
   mutate(PassFL = c("N", "Y")[1 + (ID %in% PassID$ID)])
```

Comment: For `case_when`, can we say  `mutate (PassFL= case_when(ID %in% PassID$ID~"Y", "N")` ?

Comment: You can specify `TRUE ~ "N"` which is the default value.  If not specified, the default will be `NA`

Comment: Do you mean `mutate (PassFL= case_when(ID %in% PassID$ID~"Y", FALSE ~"N"`?

Comment: @Stataq No, I meant the `TRUE ~ "N"`  updated the post

Comment: What about `mutate (Grade= case_when(Grade>8 ~"A", Grade <5 ~"C")` , if I want to add one to assign `ifelse ~B`?

Comment: That would be `mutate (Grade= case_when(Grade>8 ~"A", Grade <5 ~"C", TRUE ~ "B")` if it is the default option